# on the choice of prior distribuion in multi level model

Tags: bayesian, prior

I'm comparing the performance of the Restrected ML estimator and the Baysean method for estimating a multilevel model by Monte Carlo simulation. As I'm a beginner in Baysean analysis, I don't know how to specify the prior distribution. In general, it is preferable to use an uninformative prior for a fair comparison. But in the current case, since estimates of ML are available, I'm wondering if I can use them in the prior distribution.

For example, suppose I have an estimate of 1 with an estimated standard error of 2 for some parameter beta. Can I then use it in the prior such that beta~Normal(1, 2^2)(use in both mean and variance) or beta~Normal(1, 100^2)(use in mean only)?